# Omiting declarations of header files in source code compiled by CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I've recently been learning and becoming familiar with CMake with the hopes of overhauling a project at work to use this instead. I understand that when I create a library target and link it to a several different executable targets, that library is only compiled once.

I found that I can remove the #include in my source code while keeping the function calls to the library, and the code compiles and runs just fine. This seems like bad practice to me, and I would prefer to keep the #include to the libraries for the sake of readability. But, If I keep in all those #includes, will those libraries be compiled for each separate executable?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: Not sure what do you want. "I would prefer to keep the #include to the libraries" - `#include` includes **headers**, but libraries are **linked** (with `target_link_libraries` command in CMake).

Comment: `If I keep in all those #includes, will those libraries be compiled for each separate executable?` The preprocessor statements `#include` int the source code have nothing to do with if the library is enabled for compilation and/or will be linked with.

Comment: You shouldn't omit headers from your code unless the contents are unused.  If you use functions declared in the headers, use the headers.

Comment: It sounds as if you are not sure of the purpose of header files.  They not only enable the IDEs to provide autocompletion,etc, but they are essential for correct calling of the functions.  For example, suppose your code has the call `myfunc(123)`.  WITHOUT the header, myfunc will still be called, and it will pass the 4 bytes holding the integer 123.  That's fine if `myfunc` is declared as taking an integer (and this is probably why your code runs just fine) ...but what if `myfunc` actually takes a float ???  With the header, the compiler has the information to correctly cast 123 to 123.0.

Comment: @racraman, you're definitly right. This actually explains an failed unit test I was getting, so thank you so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The library target will be compiled once and then linked to your executables. When you modify files for your executables the library will not be recompiled. If you modify the library it will be rebuilt and the executables will get relinked.

As long as you include the headers in your library target then all executables that link the target will also link the headers. So something like this:

```
add_library(my_super_cool_lib my_header.h
                              my_code.cpp)
```

Can then be linked

```
add_executable (do_cool_stuff cool_code.cpp)
target_link_libraries(do_cool_stuff my_super_cool_lib)
```

And the headers will automatically get added to the path

If you make a library that links to other libraries then you have a choice of what to do with the headers. In CMake speak this is called the "link interface"

- You just use them locally to build the your library - PRIVATE
- You can use them locally and also "forward" them so that whoever links your library will also get those headers - PUBLIC
- You can not even use them locally but make anyone who links your library get them - INTERFACE

These are set with an optional argument:

```
target_link_libraries(do_cool_stuff <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> my_super_cool_lib)
```

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html
and  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html
The documentation is a bit dry but is very comprehensive. Just read and reread it carefully :)